# Web service accessible only through an IP

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I have some Apache CXF Web services published to the Internet, but I want one of them to be only visible to a specific IP through a VPN.

I modified the CXF XML file so that my Web service is only visible when accessing through that IP, but it is already accessible through the net.

How can I publish my Web service to only the IP only visible through the VPN?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP filtering should ideally not be done on your application layer. Think about it - You need to process the request to find out if your business code should run. You are using application resources for a request that should never have come to the application.

Use a firewall rule to filter the requests instead (Assuming of course that your firewall resides elsewhere). This will reduce the load on your server and centralize the IP filtering rules for a particular group of servers (Application / DB / File etc).

If your service is available on the internet, the rule to block requests via a specific IP do not make sense. You will need to get a list of IPs to white-list if you intend to restrict access by IP for everyone.